# Cannot execute PHP binary as non-root user in Plesk server (Linux)

Tags: php, permissions, plesk

I am running Plesk 18.0.44 on my Debian 9.13 server. It has multiple subscriptions and hence different users for these vhosts. I was always able to run `/opt/plesk/php/7.4/bin/php -v` as a vhost user (or rather some PHP commands for the applications hosted there, but php -v suffices for explaining purposes). Recently, this has stopped working with the following error message:

```
-su: /opt/plesk/php/7.4/bin/php: Permission denied
```

I don't understand that since I don't remember having changed anything about the permissions or running Plesk updates or similar. I tried adding the vhosts user group (user `laravelapp` in group `psacln`) to the php executable's permissions, so they look like this:

```
ls /opt/plesk/php/7.4/bin/php -al
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root psacln 5629184 Jun 16  2022 /opt/plesk/php/7.4/bin/php
```

I even tried setting the permissions to 777 but I just can't get it to work again. It works completely fine - as expected - when running it from root user.

What could be the possible causes for this issue and how could I troubleshoot this further?

Comment: Questions utilizing web management panels like Plesk are off topic; Debian 9 is end of life, also off topic.

Comment: In how far does that affect permission issues? @GeraldSchneider

Comment: Check all the parent folders. Also web panels are off-topic precisely because they mangle most of the system beyond recognition, including file permissions.

Comment: @Ginnungagap by parent folders you probably refer to `/opt/plesk/php/7.4`, correct? good point, I missed this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I overlooked the permissions of the parent folders of the PHP executable as @Ginnungagap pointed out.

```
chmod 755 /opt/plesk/php
```

It works. I am still unsure as to why it happened in the first place.